# hide specifc header component in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

In My application multiple pages are there, I want to hide header in one page. In below code, I have written.

```
 showHeader: boolean = false;
constructor(private router: Router){
  console.log(environment.production, "  environment.production");
    router.events.forEach((event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
           if ( event['url'] == '/pk/view/') {
                this.showHeader = false;
              } else {
                // console.log("NU")
                this.showHeader = true;
              }

        }
      });
}
```

my URL is http:localhost:1200/pk/view/13

13 means id, that's always changing.
So plz suggest me in if condition what I write

Comment: The route you want to hide the header on seems to be the parent route. Simply move the header inside the child route ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
if ( event['url'] == '/pk/view/') {
```

part to

```
if(event['url'].startsWith('/pk/view/')){
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better solution with AngularRouting:

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [{path: '', redirectTo: 'firstPage', pathMatch: 'full'},
{path: 'firstPage', component: FirstPageComponent, data: {showHeader: true}},
{path: 'secondPage', component: SecondPageComponent, data: {showHeader: false}}]
```

**app.component.ts**

```
showHeader: boolean;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  onActivate() {
    this.showHeader = this.route.firstChild.snapshot.data['showHeader'];
  }
```

**app.component.html**

```
<header class="header" *ngIf="showHeader">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>

 <router-outlet #outlet="outlet" (activate)="onActivate()"></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

showHeader: boolean = false;

constructor(private router: Router){

```
router.events.forEach((event) => {

    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
       if ( event['url'].match('/pk/view/') {
            this.showHeader = false;
          } else {
            // console.log("NU")
            this.showHeader = true;
          }

    }

  });
```

}